# Datatables not showing excel button in chrome

Tags: datatables

I am putting export excel buttons for my datatables as follow:

```
buttons: [
    {
      extend: "colvis",
      className: "btn-sm",
      columns: [ 1, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 13, 15,17,19,21,23,25,27,29,31,33 ]
    },
    {
      extend: "pageLength",
      className: "btn-sm"
    },
    {
      extend: "csv",
      className: "btn-sm",
      exportOptions: {
          columns: ':visible'
      }
    },
    {
      extend: "excel",
      className: "btn-sm",
      exportOptions: {
          columns: ':visible'
      }
    },
    {
      extend: "print",
      className: "btn-sm",
      exportOptions: {
          columns: ':visible'
      }
    },
  ],
```

It is working fine in internet explorer for all buttons but for chrome, I don't see the excel button.

I don't see an error in the console unfortunately...

Comment: Have you found the solution?

Answer (score -1):

I have faced the same issue and added the following script in my file then it started showing the buttons.

```
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/3.1.3/jszip.min.js
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.32/pdfmake.min.js
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.32/vfs_fonts.js
```

I hope you have already added the scripts flash, html5 and print. Overall your script code will look like below.

```
https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js
https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.1/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js
https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.1/js/buttons.flash.min.js
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/3.1.3/jszip.min.js
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.32/pdfmake.min.js
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.32/vfs_fonts.js
https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.1/js/buttons.html5.min.js
https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.1/js/buttons.print.min.js
```

You can check the working example [here](https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/initialisation/simple.html)